# fractional system fractional order equations

Tags: fractional-calculus

As resolved and how is the graph the phase plane of

$D^{\alpha}y_{1}(t)=2y_{1}(1-\dfrac{y_{1}}{2y_{2}}-\dfrac{y_{1}}{2})$

$D^{\alpha}y_{2}(t)=3y_{2}(1-\dfrac{y_{2}}{2y_{1}}-\dfrac{y_{2}}{2})$

where $y_{1}(0)=0.5$ ;$y_{2}(0)=0.3$

PD: $D^{\alpha}$ is 
Caputo derivative

Comment: Thhe question is not clear.

Comment: Do you want to solve the system?

Comment: Yes, missing some data?

Comment: @Frantz: What's $\alpha$?

Comment: $\alpha$ in $(0,1]$